# Oculus SDK and Visual Studio 2015 setup

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, oculus

I am very new to Visual Studio, C++ and the Oculus SDK, but have experience with Fortran, Matlab, and coding in general.

I have got the basic C++ libraries working, so #include iostream works.

I have got the LibOVR directory included, so that #include OVR_CAPI.h works.

I opened the LibOVR project into VS2015 and rebuilt it, which worked, creating a new LibOVR.lib file.

I moved the new .lib file into my project folder and also added this file path to the Linker -> Input.

But when I try to compile my own code, the basic ovr_initialize() command is said to be undefined.

I am just trying to get a basic code setup to extract the head position data from the IMU in the Oculus Rift, and eventually hoping to integrate this with some matlab code.

Here is my starting code, mostly commented out for now:

```
#include <iostream>
// Include the OculusVR SDK
#include <OVR_CAPI.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int MyNumb;

    cout << "Please, enter an integer: ";
    cin >> MyNumb;
    cin.ignore();
    cout << "You entered: " << MyNumb;
    cin.get();

    return 1;
}

void application()
{

    ovrresult result = ovr_initialize(nullptr); *THIS LINE GIVES ERROR*

    //    if (ovr_failure(result))
    //        return;
    //
    //    ovrsession session;
    //    ovrgraphicsluid luid;
    //    result = ovr_create(&session, &luid);
    //    if (ovr_failure(result))
    //    {
    //        ovr_shutdown();
    //        return;
    //    }
    //
    //    ovrhmddesc desc = ovr_gethmddesc(session);
    //    ovrsizei resolution = desc.resolution;
    //
    //    ovr_destroy(session);
    //    ovr_shutdown();

}
```

Any help getting this up and running would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Since the LibOVR project itself did compile, I've also just tried adding that project to my own and referencing it, but that didn't seem to help :/

Comment: I know its finding the header files properly now, but I guess if it was linking to the .lib properly, it should know what ovr_initialize() is? Really not sure what else that could be...